# In Rally how do I get a list of Stories I created?

Tags: rally

In Rally I see that I have to use a 'Custom App' with a Query.  However, I cannot find the correct query to use.

Have tried (CreatedBy = "myUserId") 
and (Creator" = "myUserId")
Neither work.  What is the Story attribute name that stores the name of the person who created it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, worked it out.

1. Choose Specific Project - set to Top Level Project & 'Also show items from Child Projects' ticked.
2. Type set to 'User Story'
3. Query = (CreatedBy = "my username")     -  Note, this is where I'd gone
   wrong. NOT **display** name, but **username** (in our case my email address)